# How can we send a persons conversation with bot(Built using Microsoft Power Apps) to his outlook email once the conversation is completed?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, powerapps, azure-qna-maker

I am working on creating a bot in Microsoft PowerApps using (Azure QnaMaker, Microsoft Flow Services). Our aim is to integrate this bot in Microsoft Teams to help users in the team to get the answer for faqs. I would like to know how can we send an email of conversation once his conversation is completed with the chatbot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: Could you please look at [What are conversation bots in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots)?